# Convert html (current page or child window) to image using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

is there a way to convert current rendered page or a child window to a canvas or an image using only client side scripting?

Comment: Yo want to make `print screen`?

Comment: yea something like that, i want to capture current page to an image, paste it to canvas, and edit it as i want programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for this purpose. It is plugin for jQuery which converts the webpage to canvas.

**Note:** Some styles are not appropriate when converted e.g. rotate.